# Remove Rendering Javascript And CSS in opencart store

Tags: javascript, css, rendering

I run eCommerce store http://www.celebritiesoutfits.com that on opencart platform and you know well about it that in this eCommerce world speed always matters more. When I check Google page speed and gtmetrix, I got two problems. I am not working as web developer basically I am SEO analyst and focus on sales. but I want to solved these problems. I already solve Optimize CSS Delivery using opencart cache option and that's work fine I think but after doing a lot of Google and reading many forum I can't solve this two problem. Here is the link of Google page speed test.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.celebritiesoutfits.com%2F&tab=desktop

Answer (score 0):

Step to Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content for opencart(1.x)

1. move all inline javascript to under line `echo $footer;` on
   everypage such as product.tbl , category.tbl
2. move all javascript file from `<head>` to before end of `<body>` tag
3. find your critical css path and inline css in `<head>`
4. and move no critical css file to before end of `<body>`
5. using google analytic lite version https://github.com/jehna/ga-lite

I comfirmed if you do every step you will get your score (95-100).

I done every this step. this is my score.

1. Homepage (100/100)
2. Product page (95-97/100)

Good luck.